# How to use a directive as an entry point when using angular's bootstrap function?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have an angular 1 app that's being bootstrapped onto a Java web page (legacy app) using ng-app tags. I'm trying to create a hybrid app using Angular 2's downgrade capabilities.

In order to do this I need to remove ng-app tags and use the `UpgradeModule` from `@angular/upgrade/static` and bootstrap using the `upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['myapp'])`. However, most of the components of the app, including the entry point of the app, are just plain old angular 1.2 directives.

From the examples I've seen, they are using the `controller="MenuCtrl"` syntax to add components to the page. Is it possible to use directives as the entry point to the app? e.g.

`<div my-menu-directive></div>`

Currently, nothing is showing up in the app since I've removed the ng-app tags, but the app is definitely being bootstrapped. I'm just not seeing any of the directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by wrapping the bootstrap statement in `angular.element()` like so:

```
angular.element(function() {
  upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp'], { strictDi: true });
});
```